# Remove drive given by gpo

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy

I have a couple of GPOs that deliver out mapped drives through security groups. But when I remove someone from the group, the drive is still shown. The user don't have access to it, but it is still shown. Is there a way to remove the mapped drive from the user without affecting other users that have the same mapping?

Answer (score 2):

You need to edit the GPOs.

Go into the GPO, click the Common tab, and tick the option that says, "Remove this item when it is no longer applied."

When Group Policy is next refreshed on the client machines it should update to remove the mapped drive from a user if they are no longer part of the group. If you want to force it to test this, you can run the following from the command line:

```
gpupdate /force
```

Comment: I did this. But still it didn't go away. It finally went away when I deleted the users home directory. But it's weird because I when I add the user to a group again that is supposed to give out a drive, it does nothing.

Comment: Are you talking about mapping their home directory with a GPO? That's going to require steps that are different than if you are simply talking about a generic mapped drive.